# I'm stuck with this simple PIC16F program. Help please!

Tags: pic16f

I'm just getting started with PIC programming and I'm giving up already. I just want to make an LED blink! I'm working with a PIC16F1773, MPLABX IDE v4.05 and Pickit3.

These are the configuration bits that I've defined in a header file:

```
// CONFIG1
#pragma config FOSC = INTOSC    // Oscillator Selection Bits (INTOSC oscillator: I/O function on CLKIN pin)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF      // MCLR Pin Function Select (MCLR/VPP pin function is digital input)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection (Program memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF      // Brown-out Reset Enable (Brown-out Reset disabled)
#pragma config CLKOUTEN = OFF   // Clock Out Enable (CLKOUT function is disabled. I/O or oscillator function on the CLKOUT pin)
#pragma config IESO = OFF       // Internal/External Switchover Mode (Internal/External Switchover Mode is disabled)
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF      // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor is disabled)

// CONFIG2
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // Flash Memory Self-Write Protection (Write protection off)
#pragma config PPS1WAY = ON     // Peripheral Pin Select one-way control (The PPSLOCK bit cannot be cleared once it is set by software)
#pragma config ZCD = OFF        // Zero-cross detect disable (Zero-cross detect circuit is disabled at POR)
#pragma config PLLEN = ON       // Phase Lock Loop enable (4x PLL is always enabled)
#pragma config STVREN = ON      // Stack Overflow/Underflow Reset Enable (Stack Overflow or Underflow will cause a Reset)
#pragma config BORV = LO        // Brown-out Reset Voltage Selection (Brown-out Reset Voltage (Vbor), low trip point selected.)
#pragma config LPBOR = OFF      // Low-Power Brown Out Reset (Low-Power BOR is disabled)
#pragma config LVP = ON

#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000       // INTOSC 8MHz
```

And this is the actual code:

```
#include <xc.h>

void main(void) {

OSCCON = 0x72;

TRISB = 0x00;
PORTBbits.RB0 = 0;

while (1) {

    if (PORTBbits.RB0 == 0) {
        PORTBbits.RB0 = 1;
    }else {
        PORTBbits.RB0 = 0;
    }
    // Delay for 1 sec
    for (int count = 0; count < 20; count++) {
        __delay_ms(50);
    }

}

return;
}
```

I've defined the OSCCON register as 0x72 following the datasheet but nothing lights up. I'm measuring a constant voltage of 0.42V in RB0.

EDIT:
[The datasheet:](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001810B.pdf)

I'm powering the PIC through the Pickit3. RB0 is connected to a resistor in series to the LED and to ground.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add a link to the datasheet so others could easily reference.

Comment: No experience with PIC family, but don't you have to define the directions of the PIN?

Comment: I believe TRISB = 0x00 defines all PortB pins as outputs.

Comment: Ok. Hang around. Someone would surely be helpful to you!

Comment: Is the LED right way round? (if you connect that resistor to +5V instead of RB0, does it light up?) And what happens if you start with PORTBbits.RB0 = 1;?

Comment: Yes, I double checked for in case. I'll try starting with RB0 = 1.

Comment: Have you included the header file with cfg bits from the first code segment? In your main file it seems like you include only <xc.h>

Comment: @TodorSimeonov Yes, I accidentaly skipped that line, but it is there in the actual code.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I just tried what you suggested. No changes, constant output voltage of 0.4V.

Comment: Whenever you say you are powering the PIC through a pickit3 do you mean the pickit3 is the only power source going to the microcontroller? Could you provide a schematic of your circuit as well? Software seems to be ok (without running it)

Comment: @zoder Well, the pickit3 is connected to a USB port in my computer. I configured it to supply 4.8V because the MPLAB IPE was giving me an error message if I left the default 5.0V. Then I followed the schematics to connect the programmer to the microcontroller and finally RB0 is connected to a resistor-LED-ground. Don't know how to upload an schematic here,sorry.

Comment: Try something like this:
TRISBbits.TRISB0 = 0;  // Sets RB0 as output.
LATBbits.LATB0 = 1;     // Used to set RB0 high.
// or //
LATBbits.LABB0 = 0;    // Used to set RB0 low. I don't think you need to mess with PORT.

Comment: @DanielGiesbrecht Nothing, still not working. Thank you for the suggestion tho! Do you think the oscillator has been configured correctly?

Comment: @Raúl it looks like the oscillator is configured properly.

Comment: try adding a pullup on /MCLR and enabling /MCLR.

Comment: I guess my question should have been, did you connect the power rails to the microchip ? As in the VSS( pins 8 and 19) to ground and the VDD(Pin 20) to 5V(?)

Comment: put a 10k resistor from RB0 to +5V (remove the LED) .... measure voltage on RB0  ... does it change every second? .... try the same with resistor from RB0 to GND

Comment: @jstola thanks for the help. I'm measuring constant 0V on RB0 and ground doing what you said. Why is this so complicated :/ Probably doesn't mean much, but the rest of PORTB pins do output constant voltage of 1.3V.

Comment: @zoder yes, the connections seem to be fine to me :/

Comment: @jsotola I have tried debugging the program and found out that even with the line PORTBbits.RB0 = 1; the actual state doesn't change, and the program is stuck in if(PORTBbits.RB0 == 0) (true)

Comment: You have the 4xPLL enabled in your Config Bits. If this is your intention I think your _XTAL_FREQ macro should be 32000000, not 8000000. The __delay_ms() function won't behave as expected if this is not properly set.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between your first (non-working) and your second (working) code snippets is that the first relies on the existing value of RB0.  If the external circuit is holding RB0 a particular way, even when the PIC is trying to drive it the other way, then the first won't work.

This could be the case, for example, if you don't have the LED connected correctly with the proper minimum resistance in series, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Don't ask me what was wrong with that code, but I changed it to be:

```
 while (1) {

    LATBbits.RB0 = 0;

    __delay_ms(500);

    LATBbits.RB0 = 1;

    __delay_ms(500);

}
```

This works just fine. I don't get it.

Comment: here is a possible explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623428/difference-between-port-and-latch-on-pic-18f#2623498

Comment: what happens if you use LATBbits.RB0 in your original code?